# Получение тела POST запроса на сервере

Tags: java, post

Каким образом можно вытащить `body` из `POST-запроса`.

Попробовал через `getReader`

```
private Map<String, Object> getBodyFromPostRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object> bodyParameters = new HashMap<>();

        Object[] body = request.getReader().lines().toArray();

        ...

   }
```

но в итоге в массиве `body` ничего не оказывается.

формирование запроса на клиенте:

```
function signUpAction(){

            var xhr;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            var log = document.getElementById('login').value;
            var pas = document.getElementById('password').value;

            xhr.open('POST', '/reg', true);

            var body = 'login=' + encodeURIComponent(log) +
                       '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(pas);

            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.status != 200) {
                alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); 
            } else {
                console.log( xhr.responseText ); 
            }
            };

            xhr.send(body);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо можно воспользоваться `Guava` библиотекой:

```
String test = CharStreams.toString(request.getReader());
```

Либо, если Java 8, то можно воспользоваться следующим примером

```
String body = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
```

Главное учитывать, что если ранее где-то было обращение к методам получения параметров, то `body` становится пустым. Найдено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8101279/5345294)

Answer (score 2):

Если параметры были отправлены POST-ом как `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, они должны быть доступны так:

```
Map<String, String[]> request.getParameterMap();
```

ключем в Map-е будет имя параметра, значением - массив соответсвующих значений. Там же будут и query-параметры.

Comment: т.е параметры запроса из `body` тоже должны быть доступны через данный метод? Сейчас попробовал, но в  мапе метода `getParameterMap()`  лежат только параметры явно переданные в `request-URI`

Comment: А request.getReader().lines() хоть что-то возвращает? может у вас данные с клиента не уходят вообще?

Comment: java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@1e9cee  - ну объект, то возвращает. Вопрос что с ним делать-то , видимо, стоит посмотреть доки. А на счет данных с клиента, ведь параметры из `request-URI` получается считать, или это не то, что Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: нашел в чем ошибка была. Если ранее где-то было обращение к методам получения параметров, то `body` становится пустым. Найдено [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8101279/5345294).

Comment: Но кстати используя `Map<String, String[]> request.getParameterMap();` и попытаться вытащить данные по ключу `login` или `password`  то в итоге получаем `null`

Answer (score -1):

Или можно так

```
InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = request.getInputStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky я не вижу смысла дублировать то что написали выше.  Приведенный код тривиален и взят мной с боевой платежной системы.